# как исправит syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php

не могу понять в чем проблема.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добрый день. Ошибка не имеет никакого отношения к yii2. Смотрите выше по файлам, не закрытая кавычка, скобка, точка с запятой... Вариантов много.

Comment: а закарывающие тэги все на месте?

Comment: может ли быть ошибка в хостинге?

Comment: потому что в локальном сервере все работает

Comment: Нет, не может. Уровень ошибок на хостинге выставлен выше, чем у Вас на локальном. Поэтому Вы не видите ошибку на локальном.

Comment: Посмотрите через phpinfo() error_reporting на localhost и на рабочем серверах.